# Control an Android Tablet from OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, android, remote

I have a Google Nexus 7 and a 2009 Macbook running OS X 10.9 Mavericks. I want to control the Nexus from my Macbook keyboard. I am not looking for advanced control; the ability just to browse to URLs in Chrome and/or open text files in an editor is good enough for me (but obviously, more control is better). Ideally the control would happen over bluetooth. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If your nexus 7 is rooted you can install the open-source [VNCServer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.onaips.vnc) from Google Play, and connect to it from your MacBook using your favorite VNC client, ie TightVNC, RealVNC, etc.

Of course, this will work from any device that has a VNC client, including another android or non-android phone. For example [andvnc](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=android.androidVNC) is an open-source android client that you could use on a second android device to control the first.

You can also run the VNC server on the Mac and the client on the tablet.

If you won't have Wi-Fi internet while on the go then you could enable Wi-Fi hotspot mode on the tablet (it is a bit tricky specifically for Nexus 7 but [can be done](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.hotspotcontrol&hl=en)), and connect to it from the notebook. It should also be possible to run the hotspot on the notebook instead, which will make the tablet battery last much longer.